# CSS / image vertically close to edge and text centered on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this problem where I don't know how to make 2 images that are in a container vertically and for them to be near the edge, (one left, one right) and I need text below the image that's centered on the image and for there to be text regarding the image and price. I tried flexbox. I tried adding another div. I tried figcaption and figure and I don't seem to know how to make it. I need help!

Here is the code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const playButton = document.querySelector(".play");
  const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  const closePopupButton = document.getElementById("close-popup");
  const categoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".category");
  const gameStarted = document.querySelector(".gameStarted");
  const mainPage = document.getElementById("main-page");
  const main = document.querySelector("main");
  const body = document.querySelector(".body");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  });

  closePopupButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  });

  // Add click event listeners to all category buttons
  categoryButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Close the popup
      popup.style.display = "none";

      // Hide the entire page
      mainPage.style.display = "none";

      // Start the game
      gameStarted.style.display = "block";

      main.style.display = "none";

      gameStarted.classList.add('active');
      body.classList.add('active');




    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Ink Free;
}


/*SET THE NAVIGATION BAR AT THE TOP OF THE SCREEN, REMOVE BACKGROUND COLOR AND BOX SHADOW LATER ON*/

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}


/*SETTING THE LOGO COLOR AND ANIMATION*/

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

h1>a:hover {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}


/*SETTING THE NAVBAR*/

li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

li>a:hover {
  color: bisque;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}

h1>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*BACKGROUND IMAGE SET TO FIT, CHANGE THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT VH IF NEEDED, OPACITY TO 1 OR REMOVE*/

body {
  background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/BW3DgZD.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.96;
}


/*THE MAIN TEXT AT THE MIDDLE OF THE SCREEN*/

.wwm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.title {
  font-size: 5rem;
}


/*PLAY BUTTON NEEDS JAVASCRIPT*/

.play {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0rem 3rem;
  background-color: rgb(122, 64, 72);
  color: white;
}

.play:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: .20s ease-in-out;
}


/*chatgpt*/

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.popup-content {
  background: white;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

.categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.category {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem
}

.close-popup {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #DC3545;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.gameStarted {
  display: none;
}

.gameStarted.acive {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30rem;
}

.divv {
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.the-images {
  display: flex;
}

.body.active {
  background-image: url('https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/black-gradient-b9-1920x1080.jpg');
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Whats Worth More</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <main>
    <div id="main-page">
      <header class="navbar">
        <h1><a href="#">WWM</a></h1>
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Play</a>
              <a href="#">Categories</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <section class="main">
      <div class="wwm">
        <h2 class="title">Whats Worth More</h2>
        <button class="play">Play</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="popup" id="popup">
      <div class="popup-content">
        <h2>Select a Category</h2>
        <div class="categories">
          <button class="category">Random</button>
          <button class="category">Boats & Planes</button>
          <button class="category">Watches</button>
          <button class="category">Houses</button>
          <button class="category">Cars</button>
          <button class="category">Drinks</button>
          <button class="category">Food</button>
          <button class="category">Companies</button>
          <button class="category">Art</button>
          <button class="category">Clothing</button>
          <button class="category">Technology</button>
          <button class="category">Electronics</button>
          <button class="category">Jewelry</button>
          <button class="category">Collectibles</button>
        </div>
        <button class="close-popup" id="close-popup">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="gameStarted">
    <h2 class="vs">VS</h2>
    <h3 class="more">More</h3>
    <h3 class="less">Less</h3>

    <div class="divv">
      <img class="the-images" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHed0BLjkGmOcMGIydZ0T6zP4wG-jsd7wz_sPMrFCWJD_ryci7MYKxXaCpg3upBGxwcKOpqv5k-4x1hyR7tEE1At8ppJgBY7sxgGF9LlnIUOfqXyDiLmAfgIdBVILIm5BvyPuewFNM4keNBnzQ1dv6uzCVglDanjP2Ht3mJHIigqIbJtX-dJ1Zy9E9tHBHI71_ua8yrjGT4Kh2pSKT--SBPIN5TY9qnyZi2Ka40mhL7T5A-h1BghJ7i4KEvHvLHd9cNl5NnwGbGFfv_AZs7yXNtQ_qlgus6oRX-i4aG96x3bbsGUzjwF2L-zC1L9iofmuRLx5h9uQ3PyVN7sUbclZ7LY1pjV4zvOqWRkU6RiBKkV8DlkHAsC4USs2f4Ziudtr5As7ju0mRMCDUA6sHAr14Un2mjNEABzk_2LvjNqrx_lgea_OQm9hqMtPt5jZ0DeGhVPxANxzZYZUUqSUyyD0vDRer6Jf4mkEYIay9fYWkDl1Nt-SgnB5Va70iPZsSeWe-Zco2HAJ6aeErRUcFGY19r8XY2aiLozdoxPbIIkgn85DgA_NFKguUky4VyILccilG-_cYLiqRNxA8Wns9yp2F45VYfl6QjwBDeA-MKt3wfGihQYACTMWwz60_CIzipJgg2v1utVt97KL7YAS3Y4KVc8Qn-GoKnCCkHprKrofD1fVF1Yv-7eWX87z0bzWKLQ_TM4Wfu2in5QzrFZwFuVQvJjAGrNxKnNtQRtGVXCENM1ahM0BTeao_AvLAeDj5Nhb4JArld8qb_exzRGHdOsuQWgkdcHAq-Nz0wKhtLEO8qvQHOv2ORyg1cDCS15rLSOuthkyet2oIJjzuY3hjlq8nzjTC7D-bIhYeh_eIwQjCOQXiu5RXrGzVMUX218D-bhYJ2hIQ9sFKTIXMB7T0vg6ET7lR9kOmvWQjq0Fl9Kbdg02MhNlgGFrumAzw=w693-h360-s-no?authuser=0">



      <img class="the-images" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeQcIFyZ4zdIPT5TWdBNc-VaPVxue2FZipOANSp2RIhtSlJIbcCX6PKATvn2uOoei0-6TnwgXkTG4PCNs6MKVG81WYIPWd0XBaBGsumd3KK9uMEucXZ0iRRAejixjQqTzfFMGHO5JKjRzJze0cGpnSrfq3rrQ6whawkp5Pe8EJ-9KOL_bXuPT0zWtryp1BTVcXFZUNQqWUrBY_G0dwsSa97Lk2NipzXFEBhyKngaI3H6tXprq4Jr1ddas29SVbeKIVHAGsyBm_piZ4OScdFVKU92a3tG-eh-IN6Go3ZlBduAkh1H0zKW3pVAk6kRCZoKO3YR_AiO_D4lh0qxa7HMNxirfKnnQVKr8Z4j1vBMkguTh7RP-7VSYb58CV7tRonyXtveg1tjgITSILO4SBMrbLIcXuzeZrwW6NtC-OEtd8H7dp0VRAubjwM8l6xr6YsdybC8zsBY_l0KUptxvI1gqOqwA0s2nHbtQ65Ntlx1-AUvU1eiFGZHtYzZIj3ofFCJnBzdPRZYl0xYeMAoMD91o8MvfUHhAqwyYSSbGlNmPvPpvzxUmjfwCb4kVJV1VutvCU0NO6MKi1uNZ4eOXu3A7yCtDGNn1i4PVeFZS2YiX4JbQ4d77kg8jAQ08DTwVxdcvfK1vo97vVaJQsxspHdAxH3pmozRe5DNJSzLjpsVZsWoCOTN7z7uHDv0X9ybNg-8qcRkp80itfAN0kJWTOh1uRJWHW9EgMtVHPxYfLH9fgamn7wSFXN5L5TSVszofdw-mZRYRiZ8449U85cfaOY5CQhhpoe_OqqC81ox6iw6rxQHCYCBa6c9mfPcePUo9cKw_4ZbaFUW5DQINdnt3cDBfBmU13sCqug9XFhmpmFm9Bil7weBgMcLcfnG7xaCwJroJrK5vdqKx1QGXkfhbGuANdHYUGg-aDybyVnU4ZUfH5ILjLmwcCAgflr0g=w719-h347-s-no?authuser=0">
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="questions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there for a question about aligning some images. I wouldn't think you'd need any JavaScript for such a question... Can you please whittle the code down to a [mre] that is just about the code you are asking about?